# How to prove that if $\mathcal F_1\subseteq \mathcal F_2$ then $\sigma(X,\mathcal F_1)$ is weaker than $\sigma(X,\mathcal F_2)$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $\mathcal F_1,\mathcal F_2$ be a family of functions from $(X,\tau)$ into $(Y_\alpha,\tau_\alpha)$ such that $\mathcal F_1\subseteq \mathcal F_2$ then

I want to show that the weak topology generated by $\mathcal F_1$ on $X$, $\sigma(X,\mathcal F_1)$, is weaker than the weak topology generated by $\mathcal F_1$ on $X$, $\sigma(X,\mathcal F_2)$

**My attempt:**

Let $u_\alpha\in\tau_\alpha$ then $f^{-1}_\alpha(u_\alpha)$, such that $f_\alpha\in \mathcal F_1$, is open set in $X$.

Since $\mathcal F_1\subseteq \mathcal F_2$ then $f_\alpha\in \mathcal F_2$

Hence $f^{-1}_\alpha(u_\alpha)$, such that $f_\alpha\in \mathcal F_2$, is open set in $X$

Therefore, $\sigma(X,\mathcal F_1)$ is weaker than $\sigma(X,\mathcal F_2)$

Is this proof enough?

Comment: The weak topology is by **definition** the smallest topology that makes a family continuous. This fact is just a straightforward application of that fact and we don't need its subbase or anything else.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Is there a way to prove it using my method. i.e. by take a set in the weak topology $\sigma(X,\mathcal F_1)$ and proving that it exists in $\sigma(X,\mathcal F_2)$?

Comment: The subbase for $\sigma(X,\mathcal{F}_1)$ is a subset of that for $\sigma(X,\mathcal{F}_2)$. You need to have the lemma that if subbases for topologies are subsets so are the topologies, which is essentially a minimality argument again.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\tau'$ be any topology that makes all functions in $\mathcal F_2$ continuous.

So $\tau'$ makes all functions in $\mathcal F_1$ continuous a fortiori.

So by definition of the weak topology $\sigma(X,\mathcal{F}_1) \subseteq \tau'$.

Now take $\tau'=\sigma(X,\mathcal F_2)$...

Comment: Is there a way to prove it using my method. i.e. by take a set in the weak topology $\sigma(X,\mathcal F_1)$ and proving that it exists in $\sigma(X,\mathcal F_2)$?

Comment: @gbd that's not what you were doing, you reason about the subbases, not *all* open sets.